# How to remove spaces between parentheses in a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string from which I need to remove spaces between two specific characters/words, here is the example:

```
String Test = " testcase s(this_one_has_no_space) and s(this_one_has_ space )"
```

I want to remove the spaces between every following 's(' and ')'. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Can you have nested parenthesis? And what about unbalanced parenthesis?

Comment: No yet, We can have nested parenthesis, but i just want to remove spaces between "s("  and ")" . when parenthesis starts with 's' then it can not be any nested in the following openclose parantheses. s()

Comment: look for replaceAll();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        String test = " testcase s(this_one_has_no_space) and s(this_one_has_ space )";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("s\\([^\\)]*\\s+[^\\)]*\\)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
        while (m.find()) {
            String temp = m.group();
            test = test.replace(temp, temp.replaceAll("\\s", ""));
        }
        System.out.println(test);
```

Try this and see if your problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to capture the inner parenthesis then, replace that string's spaces then put
the string back in. If Java can do a callback this will be ok ..

```
 //  s\\(([^()\\t\\ ]*[\\t\\ ][^()]*)\\)     

 s                                           
 \(                                         
 (                          # (1 start)      
      [^()\t\ ]*                           
      [\t\ ]                               
      [^()]*                                 
 )                          # (1 end)        
 \)
```